# Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit: Resolution reset after reboot / HDMI display wrong colors

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, hdmi

### **Situation**

I have attached my pc, which has a nvidia geforce GT-610 graphics card, to my samsung led tv with an hdmi cable. I have ubuntu 14.04 installed.

### **Problem**

The image doesn't seem to be correct. It seems to be using too much red. By default it's using the xorg graphics driver. But even with the different Nvidea drivers the problem doesn't go away. Only when I use the nvidea driver and change the resolution from 1920x1080 to 1600x900 the image gets a little bit darker and the red glow disappears. The problem is that after a reboot the resolution is reset back to 1920x1080.

### **Things I've tried**

- Creating a script which sets the resolution to 1600x900 at startup. This works a little. I see that my tv switches 3 times from resolution but than remains on 1600x900. But when I switch off the tv and turn it on 30 minutes later its back to 1920*1080
- Switching different drivers in the additional drivers section
- Trying different color profiles but the image didnt improve
- Trying a different hdmi cable, still same result.

### **Further research**

Besides the resolution problems, I got also some dialogs like: A system program problem detected. So I figured that my installation was just messed up and therefore I started a fresh install on a vm which I later convert to my psychial system. The strange thing is that after the fresh install of 14.04/13.10 & 13.04 I keep having the problems:

- Resolution is reset after reboot
- On 13.10 I received after a few reboots again the "A system program problem dialog"
- When I check the /var/crash reports I find that is saying something about gnome-settings deamon.
- Even with unity 14.04 the resolution is reset

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Have you opened system settings, and changed the colour profile there?

Comment: I have tried to use different color profiles, but the the image didnt improve. In the nvidia settings you could adjust the amount of each color used, although you can cfix it with that, its kinda error prone solution. But im wondering why colors are correct when I lower my resolution